# Windows app to turn a bluetooth dongle into a keyboard to control other devices

Tags: windows, android, mouse, keyboard, bluetooth

This is a bit unusual, because everything I've found by searching is the other way around.

I'd like to control my android tablet and phone over bluetooth from a Windows computer. So I guess I'm looking for an app which can fake a generic bluetooth keyboard and mouse from the usb-bluetooth dongle connected to a PC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/315400/can-i-make-my-pc-act-as-a-bluetooth-human-interface-device despite the intended target to be controlled being different.

Comment: I don't think I want to hit the limitations of a HID if I can just do plain bluetooth keyboard and mouse devices. Also, the definition for duplicate questions says "exact same question", and you yourself note that the intended target is different, which makes the questions different. If the answers to different questions are the same, that doesn't make questions duplicates of one another. But it is related.

Comment: Bluetooth keyboards are HID devices.  HID is the protocol, not the type of device.

Comment: ah shoot, then I guess the same limitations will apply >:I